# Notice: Undefined variable total not working in php 5.4

Tags: php, mysql, function

```
$query11 =  "select * from linkat_link where  emailuser='$email2'  or   linkname='$domain_name2'   ";
$result11 = mysql_query("$query11");
while($addrow11=mysql_fetch_row($result11)){
$dyoon=$dyoon + $addrow11["12"];
}
echo "$dyoon";
```

i have problem after upgrade my server to php 5.4

This in previous versions collects number

example :
in the  rows

```
$addrow11["12"] = 12 
$addrow11["12"] = 23
 $dyoon = 35
```

Comment: This is not a question.

Comment: there is no `total` variable in your code!

Comment: There is no `$total` in your post. Also you don't need to quote variables if you want to use them as a parameter. And the mysql_ extension is deprecated use MySqli or PDO.

Comment: This in previous versions php  collects number

Comment: There is still no variable `$total`. And if your query works you should get that result. Please edit the question to outline exactly what you actual question is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe try

```
echo $dyoon;
```

instead of

```
echo "$dyoon";
```

like Rangad suggested in his/her comment

Also set $dyoon before while loop

```
$dyoon = 0;
while($addrow11=mysql_fetch_row($result11)){
$dyoon=$dyoon + $addrow11["12"];
}
echo $dyoon;
```

Comment: thanks DrSpy is work now